# Shell dynamic variable as condition inside AWK

Tags: if-statement, awk, sh

I have a `sh` (POSIX) script where I'm trying to choose a host from a list of hosts (SSH), this list have some interesting info along the hosts names, like free memory available, users already connected... I want the user of my script to choose what characteristics should have the script in consideration to choose a suitable host from said list.

As this characteristics are optional, what I thought was to build a conditional statment in a shell variable (just text) based in the options the user have chosen. Then, pass this variable to AWK to extract those suitable hosts and choose one of them randomly. By the moment, saild statment or `FILTER` could look like this:

```
FILTER='$6 <=MAXUSERS && $7 <=MAXUSERS'
FILTER='$6 <=MAXUSERS && $7 <=MAXUSERS && $9 >=10'
FILTER='$6 <=MAXUSERS && $7 <=MAXUSERS && $9 >=10 && $11 >=8'
```

($X are just positional parameters as characteristics of the host, I know theirs positions and should not change as long as the HTML source doesnt change either) I build those statments with this piece of code:

```
setUpFilter(){
    FILTER='$6 <=MAXUSERS && $7 <=MAXUSERS'
    if [ -n "$CPUNUM" ]; then
        FILTER="${FILTER} && \$9 >=$CPUNUM"
    fi
    if [ -n "$FREEMEM" ]; then
        FILTER="${FILTER} && \$12 >=$FREEMEM"
    fi
}
```

Once the statment is built, I use this:

```
filterHosts(){
    setUpFilter
    for HOST in $(echo "$AVAILABLEHOSTS"); do # $AVAILABLEHOSTS is a list with only the hosts names
        HOSTDATA=$(echo "$REPORTCLEAN" | egrep -A 11 "$HOST") # Report clean is a list of hosts and its data extracted from an HTML file
        FILTEREDHOSTS=${FILTEREDHOSTS}$(echo $HOSTDATA | awk -v FILTER="$FILTER" -v MAXUSERS=5 '{
            if (FILTER)
                print $1 "\\n"
        }')
    done
}
```

However this does not work as expected since the "filter" seems like doing nothing, as all the hosts are stored in `$FILTEREDHOSTS` like the condition was `true` in all the iterations (And I'm not sure why), however when I manually set the condition inside the AWK script, the "filter" works as expected:

```
filterHosts(){
    setUpFilter
    for HOST in $(echo "$AVAILABLEHOSTS"); do # $AVAILABLEHOSTS is a list with only the hosts names
        HOSTDATA=$(echo "$REPORTCLEAN" | egrep -A 11 "$HOST") # Report clean is a list of hosts and its data extracted from an HTML file
        FILTEREDHOSTS=${FILTEREDHOSTS}$(echo $HOSTDATA | awk -v MAXUSERS=5 '{
            if ($6 <=MAXUSERS && $7 <=MAXUSERS && $9 >=10)
                print $1 "\\n"
        }')
    done
}
```

`$HOSTDATA` looks like this, btw: `HOSTNAME PARAM2 PARAM3 ... PARAM12`, so I want to retrieve `$1` (The host name) based on some of the params matching some values.

I know that this second piece of code works because I checked the list manually after executing it.

I've tried to make AWK print `FILTER`, and apparently the statment is correct since it prints just like the firsts examples I wrote above, with nothing expanded or unexpected things, literally like the examples.

I'm not that good in AWK so I have no idea what could be happening, I'm not even sure if this is an issue of AWK at all. By the other hand, I'm wondering if this is the best approach I could get for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

As some users suggested, I moved the 'filter' built to the awk script itself, so I ended up with this:

```
filterHosts(){
    for HOST in $(echo "$AVAILABLEHOSTS"); do
        HOSTDATA=$(echo "$REPORTCLEAN" | egrep -A 11 "$HOST")
        FILTEREDHOSTS=${FILTEREDHOSTS}$(echo $HOSTDATA | awk -v cpunum="$CPUNUM" -v freemem="$FREEMEM" -v MAXUSERS="$1" '{
            filter = $6 <=MAXUSERS && $7 <=MAXUSERS
            if (length(cpunum) != 0)
                filter = filter && $9 >= cpunum
            if (length(freemem) != 0)
                filter = filter && $12 >= freemem
            if (filter)
                print $1 "\\n"
        }')
    done
}
```

Apparently this works with no issues at first glance, so I consider this issue 'semi-solved' since I not sure why the previous code did not work, but I have a different piece of code that works.

Comment: Notice how you're using double quotes in some places? It needs to be single quotes if you don't want the shell to run expansions before awk can see them.

Comment: That said, you can build your conditional logic _in awk_ if you pass your variable through; that way you don't need to do code generation in the first place.

Comment: ...btw, as an aside -- all-caps variables are in the namespace used for variables that modify or reflect behavior of the shell and other POSIX-defined utilities. You should use lower-case names for variables you define yourself; that way you don't overwrite variables defined by the shell by mistake.

Comment: ("if you pass your variable through" -- we have quite a lot of preexisting Q&A entries that boil down to "how do I pass a shell variable to awk?", the answer being "use `-v`")

Comment: I'm seconding @CharlesDuffy suggestion to move the filter building into awk and pass into awk the variables necessary to do so. Otherwise you are in this code-smell, anti-pattern of defining code to be eval'd later on.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'll take on consideration the uppercase issue. Will also re-think the 'filter build' to keep it inside the awk script (As other users suggests too), surely that will solve the problem but I still don't get why this is happening at first.

Comment: To help yourself understand the "why", `bash -x yourscript` is your friend.

Comment: BTW, answers should be added _as answers_, not as edits to the question.

Comment: Another aside: Instead of `for HOST in $(echo "$AVAILABLEHOSTS"); do` you probably want `for HOST in $AVAILABLEHOSTS; do` -- though that too is a code smell / antipattern, insofar as you're word-splitting a string instead of using the native bash array type to hold a list of items.

Comment: (To a limited extent, the issues caused by `for item in $string` are discussed in [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and [BashPitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), though neither is _quite_ squarely on point).

Comment: In your latest script: `if (length(cpunum) != 0)` is an odd and inefficient way of testing `if (cpunum != "")`. You're still using all upper case variable names which could be clobbering any environment variables. Please read the previous comments you received. Also copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck,net and fix the issues it tells you about.

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that the way your code is written right now (looping on hosts, parsing the same data as stored in a string repeatedly for each host) is a reasonable way to do whatever it is you're trying to do. If you post a new question including a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can help you.

Comment: I just looked again - i THINK you think you're building up a filter in a string and then testing that filer once at the end of your script. That's not what you're doing. You're executing the filter at each step and storing it's result in a string for evaluation again at the next step. That's inefficient and error-prone and just complicates your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your "semi-final" solution suffers from [useless use of `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) and can be refactored to

```
filterHosts(){
    for host in $AVAILABLEHOSTS; do
        hostdata=$(echo "$REPORTCLEAN" | egrep -A 11 "$host")
        filteredhosts=${filteredhosts}$(echo $hostdata |
        awk -v cpunum="$CPUNUM" -v freemem="$FREEMEM" -v MAXUSERS="$1" '{
            filter = $6 <=MAXUSERS && $7 <=MAXUSERS
            if (length(cpunum) != 0)
                filter = filter && $9 >= cpunum
            if (length(freemem) != 0)
                filter = filter && $12 >= freemem
            if (filter)
                print $1 "\\n"
        }')
    done
}
```

The lack of quotes around `echo $hostdata` is flattening the `egrep` results onto a single line, which would often be a bug; but without access to this data, I can't refactor the Awk script accordingly.

Https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization explains why this uses lower case for all the variables. The rest of the script should ideally be refactored similarly.